# CherryPy - Prevent using path basename as argument

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm exposing the following handler:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@auth
def test(self, id=0, **params):
    pass
```

It is my intention that id will always be an integer. In the @auth decorator, I check cherrypy.request.params to make sure that id is not set, or is an integer.

I've discovered that the following call bypasses this check:

```
GET /test/blah.php
```

In this call, id=blah.php, the basename of the path, and cherrypy.request.params is empty.

I'd like to return 404 rather than set /blah.php as the id argument. This will prevent automated scanners from causing errors on my server by navigating to fictitious URLs.

How can I prevent CherryPy from using part of the path as the first argument? In this case, it should call id=0. If id wasn't a keyword argument, it should raise 404.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fortunate enough to be able to use python3, using the keyword-only syntax would be the easiest way.

```
def test(self, *, id=0, **params):
    pass
```

In python2, you can simulate the same manually.

```
def test(self, **params):
    id = params.pop('id', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see.  ok well you could just accept all variables and test that they are integers...

```
@cherrypy.expose
@auth
def test(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ReGex = re.compile("^[0-9]+$")
    if(kwargs.get('id') == None or not ReGex.match(kwargs['id'])):
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError(403)

    # else legit user
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, sorry. That would work, but I don't have a blah.php page. Automated scanners are causing errors on my server by going to these fictitious URLs. I'd like CherryPy to use id=0 rather than id=blah.php.